# How can I disable a Heroku Worker from code?

Tags: java, heroku

I'm using Java and I would like to know if there is any way I can disable a Worker from code, thanks.

Comment: I am not a subject matter expert, but, it looks like a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be required to provide a suggestion to this question, such as code attempts, the code provided in the [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/9xQLJpdH) (added as a [comment to an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70893490/how-can-i-disable-a-heroku-worker-from-code#comment125338090_70893932))

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has a [CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/command-line) (Command Line Interface) available, which you can use to do all kinds of things with Heroku.

So in Java you can do a system call to that CLI to scale the resource of your liking.

Here is a basic snippet that you can use to execute commands.

*! Warning: if you accept random user input in this first string then bad things can happen, make sure to or hardcode the input or to sanitize the user input if you want to make it dynamically !*

```java
String command = "command to do something with Heroku";
 
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
 
// deal with OutputStream to send inputs
process.getOutputStream();
 
// deal with InputStream to get ordinary outputs
process.getInputStream();
 
// deal with ErrorStream to get error outputs
process.getErrorStream();
```

Comment: This is my code right now [link](https://pastebin.com/9xQLJpdH) but it throws Invalid credentials provided. The way Heroku CLI makes you login is pretty difficult so I would I do that in code?

Comment: I think I've just found a solution: using Formation in Heroku Platform API seems to work without any problems. Thank you anyway :)